# Constructing AJAX url values from a ServiceStack-backed SPA

Tags: servicestack

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application, that serves as the host for my ServiceStack AppHost.  Everything is working fine in development, but in my first test deployment, I realized I neglected to handle differences in my AJAX url values between my environments (development/test/staging/deployment).  My app is really just a Knockout-based SPA that makes calls to ServiceStack, so MVC merely provides the hosting.

So my javascript has this:

```
        self.DoSomething = function (event) {
            // here is my problem.  the service url is  
            // specific to the current environment             
            var service_url = '/api/some_method';
            $.ajax({
                url: service_url,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                  // do something
                }
            })
        };
```

In a 'normal' ASP.NET MVC app, where I'm calling controller actions, I'd do this:

```
var service_url = '@Url.Action("MyControllerAction", "MyController")'
```

The best solution I have so far is this:

```
var service_url = '@Url.Content("~")api/some_method';
```

It works fine, but it looks uglier than I would have thought possible for a single line of code.  It also looks like the sort of thing that could get messed up without noticing until the AJAX calls start failing...

My inclination would be to wrap this up into a js helper file, which could be referenced from any similar page, but the js helper wouldn't get resolved by the razor engine.

Does anyone know if there is a 'best practice' way to do this?